# JQuery Mobile prevent back page navigation

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, navigation, stoppropagation

I've seen a couple of posts on this topic but none of them offered a suitable solution.

Once a user navigates to the next page I want to prevent him from going back to the previous ones. I have no back buttons in my pages but back navigation is still possible by tablet/phone device back button.

I believe it's something with `preventDefault` and `stopImmediatePropagation` but I don't know how to target the device/browser back button.

Comment: you want to prevent user from navigating backwards all time? or under a certain condition?

Comment: @Omar, I want to prevent all back navigation on all time. I know how to prevent it on certain links only, but not as a whole ..

Comment: @Omar , thanks but I found a way of doing it right, added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good way of doing this, tested it with android and it's working fine.

**First** of all, make sure you have cordova.js added to your library.

**Second**, add the following just above the closing header tag, inside:

```
<script>
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
}

function deviceReady() {
   document.addEventListener('backbutton', backButtonCallback, false);
}

function backButtonCallback() {
   navigator.notification.confirm('do you want to exit the app?',confirmCallback);
}
function confirmCallback(buttonIndex) {
   if(buttonIndex == 1) {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
}
</script>
```

**Third** and final, change your starting body tag with:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Comment: you can achieve this without cordova. You can redirect user to another page when browser's back button is used.

Comment: @omar, That is also true but I need this to work for built android apps that anyway require cordova and I also need it to work on hardware back button.

Comment: if you are already using cordova, then it's another issue :) here's a jQM way http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5hxc8Lqr/

Comment: Well, I'm not actually making any use of cordova, it's needed when creating the android app from html5, css and jqm :) I'll check it right away :)